# Guest additionals: Kernel headers not found for target kernel

Tags: linux, virtualbox, centos, kernel

I've been having a difficult time getting Guest Additions to install on my Oracle Linux 7. I have VirtualBox version 6.1.4.
I have guest additions version 6.0.4

The machine had 4.14.35-1902.7.3.1 kernel version. I succesed installed it a kernel version
4.1.12-124.24.3 on it. To do so, I followed the instructions from this page: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-change-default-kernel-boot-with-old-kernel/

Newest article: (https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-change-the-default-kernel-boot-from-old-kernel-in-centos-rhel-8/)

Installation steps:

```
yum -y install kernel-uek-firmware-4.1.12-124.24.3.el6uek.noarch.rpm
yum -y install kernel-uek-4.1.12-124.24.3.el6uek.x86_64.rpm
yum -y install kernel-uek-devel-4.1.12-124.24.3.el6uek.x86_64.rpm

awk -F\' '$1=="menuentry " {print $2}' /etc/grub2.cfg
grub2-set-default 0 #depends on the above result
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
And reboot.
```

When I run `uname -r` I got this:
4.1.12-124.24.3.el6uek.x86_64

At this point, everything it's fine until I have to install Guest Additions.

When I run ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run this error is returned:

```
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 6.0.4 Guest Additions for Linux........
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing installed version 6.1.4 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Starting.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel
modules.  This may take a while.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: To build modules for other installed kernels, run
VirtualBox Guest Additions:   /sbin/rcvboxadd quicksetup <version>
VirtualBox Guest Additions: or
VirtualBox Guest Additions:   /sbin/rcvboxadd quicksetup all
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Kernel headers not found for target kernel
4.1.12-124.24.3.el6uek.x86_64. Please install them and execute
  /sbin/rcvboxadd setup
modprobe vboxguest failed
The log file /var/log/vboxadd-setup.log may contain further information.
```

I reran `/sbin/rcvboxadd setup` but it was the same log message.
The log file just showed up "modprobe vboxguest failed". I also exported KERN_DIR environment variable as
`/usr/src/kernels/4.1.12-124.24.3.el6uek.x86_64`

What I am doing wrong? Does anyone knows how to install it properly?
If anyone has any ideas I would really appreciate feedback.

Answer (score 16):

On my CentOS 6 VM, the kernel development package was not installed, so I had to do:

```
yum install kernel-devel
```

This, however, created a mismatch between the kernel development version (`2.6.32-754.31.1.el6`) and the actual kernel version (`2.6.32-754.el6`). You can check all these versions using `yum list kernel*`. So, I then updated my kernel version and rebooted:

```
yum update kernel kernel-headers
reboot now
```

On my system, the Guest Additions `autorun.sh` file still did not complete after this, because the `gcc` package was missing:

```
yum install gcc
```

After installing `gcc`, the Guest Additions installation succeeded, and they took effect after another reboot.

Comment: This answer basically worked for me. For me there was no mismatched version, but I did have a lot other missing packages. The error log guided me through which packages to `yum install`. At the end of it all I rebooted and now things seem to be working nicely.

Comment: Only this actually worked for me. Before that I had used https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-centos-7-linux as prerequisite installation before I had installed the guest-edition, that led to the above error that this article handled correctly. Virtual Box 6.1 and Centos7. It saved my time and from frustations:-)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure, but i think even if you are loading the correct kernel, the **devel** package that include **headers** since the newest kernel versions is incompatible with the current kernel, to check this :

```
rpm -qa | grep kernel
```

Then install the correct **devel** version and make sure **gcc** and **make** are installed :

```
yum -y install gcc make
yum -y install kernel-uek-devel-`uname -r`
```

if the repo is not available, execute this before

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo=yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL6/UEKR4/archive/x86_64
sudo yum install -y kernel-uek-4.1.12-124.24.3.el6uek.x86_64
sudo yum install -y kernel-uek-devel-4.1.12-124.24.3.el6uek.x86_64
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. 
```[root@devbox ~]# yum -y install kernel-uek-devel-`uname -r`
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
No package kernel-uek-devel-4.1.12-124.24.3.el6uek.x86_64 available.
Error: Nothing to do```

Comment: Try to add this repo : http://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL6/UEKR4/archive/x86_64/

Answer (score 3):

I was getting Issues even after getting the proper packages. I first made sure to check and update my kernel headers...

```
    yum update kernel kernel-headers
```

...made sure I had appropriate pre-reqs installed..

```
    yum -y install gcc make
```

...Then I forced the correct version by running:

```
    sudo yum -y install kernel-devel-$(uname -r)
```

This is all assuming that `uname -r` is displaying the correct value.

Comment: Another thing that may help is to set the KERN_DIR environment variable. to the kernel source code directory.

```$ export KERN_DIR=/usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)```

THEN you can try again with guest additions.

Answer (score 2):

here's the code from the Virtual Box script:

```
        if test -d /lib/modules/"$TARGET_VER"/build; then
            setup_modules "$TARGET_VER"
            depmod
        else
            info "Kernel headers not found for target kernel $TARGET_VER. [...]
```

The variable `$TARGET_VER` is defined as:

```
test -z "${TARGET_VER}" && TARGET_VER=`uname -r`
```

So I'd check if `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build` points to a valid directory with kernel source...

Answer (score 2):

The message says:

```
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Kernel headers not found for target kernel
5.3 (in may case).
```

the **target kernel** is the kernel version the OS is using.
you can see it with:

```
uname -r

5.3
```

The **kernel headers** are made by the kernel-devel package:
you can see the versión of kernel-devel with:

```
dnf list kernel-devel*

kernel-devel.x86_64                             5.10
```

I have Kernel headers for kernel version 5.10, but virtual box is trying to use headers for kernel versión 5.3.

You have to boot the OS using kernel version 5.10 instead of 5.3

to see if you have kernel versión 5.10:

```
dnf list kernel-core*

kernel-core.x86_64                             5.3                           @updates 
kernel-core.x86_64                             5.9                          @updates 
kernel-core.x86_64                             5.10
```

There it is.

Now you just need to  update grub2 so it can see the new kernel versión:

```
grub2-mkconfig –o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg

reboot
```

Now check again which kernel version the OS is using:

```
 uname –r

 5.10
```

this solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Simple one-liner from [Dev2QA.com](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-resolve-virtualbox-guest-additions-kernel-headers-not-found-for-target-kernel-error/):

```
yum install "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"
```

Answer (score 0):

On your Linux, you must install the Kernel-devel version to match the target kernel using this link https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/UEKR6/x86_64/

- Then reboot, and Install the Guest Addition again.

The guest additions should work fine.